# What shrubs/flowers are deer resistant?

Tags: plant-recommendations, landscaping

I am redoing the landscaping around my house and there are always tons of deer nearby. What types of plants are deer resistant but still look pretty(flowering). Location is in Wisconsin. The landscaping will get moderate sunlight.

Comment: Any plants inside a tall fence?  Seriously though they eat different things at different times of the year.  It depends on how hard the winter is, how many deer, what else is there to eat....

Answer (score 6):

https://njaes.rutgers.edu/deerresistance/

A great list of what plants are good for deer resistance and what will get hurt. Keep in mind you are more than likely able to put certain plants by others to keep the ones that can not safe. They do not actually keep the deer away, but the deer hate eating some of these plants, which should keep them away. But like I said, plant the ones the hate by the ones they like or love! Hope you find this list of great use!

Comment: Pour the blood from cooking meat around  the shrubs also, as they will smell like an animal carcass.

Comment: I like the idea of that. But how would the blood treat a plant? I know meat is not the best thing to give them and everything, but what about the blood?

Comment: it smells like a fresh wolf kill, and the native americans used fish/animals to fertilize plants, so I'm not sure, but I would think the nutrients from it would work similar to blood and bone meal.